# should I check pointers in such situations?

Tags: c++, if-statement, pointers, unreal-engine4

I'm new to programming and game development in general
every time I read and hear that pointers are a nightmare I want to ask if it is necessary to check pointers in such cases as shown below?

```
// create a component of a certain type and return a pointer to data of this type
StaticMeshCompt = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMesh"));
if (StaticMeshCompt)
{
   // further work with the component
}
```

Comment: Is the create function guaranteed to return non-null?

Comment: actually I don't know about guarantee

Comment: If it's not guaranteed then you *should* check if the pointer is valid, which you're doing correctly here.

Comment: A better question is, what's in the `else` branch? What amazing code are you going to write to make up for the fact that you cannot create an UE object?

Comment: 'pointers are a nightmare' - conquer them with smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`). Takes 10 minutes to learn, no more nightmares

Comment: @pm100 unreal engine doesn't use the standard library

Comment: @MattWilson2003 - I missed that tag

Comment: @MattWilson2003 just because a library doesn’t, it doesn’t mean _you_ can’t. I’ve used smart pointers with pure c libraries. If you understand the ownership semantics of the external library, you can wrap them in smart pointers appropriately.

Comment: @Taekahn In unreal this would be `TUniquePtr` and `TSharedPtr`, but it's only relevant for non UObject classes. UObjects are lifetime managed by the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no need to check the pointer. The cases where `CreateDefaultSubobject` could return `nullptr` are :

- The class passed is `nullptr` (It's guaranteed to be valid for any `UObject`).
- The class has the abstract flag (Not the case for
  `UStaticMeshComponent`).
- Allocation itself fails due to lack of free memory (At that point,
  you've got other problems).

Answer (score 1):

As David G and ChrisMM said, it is necessary to check the pointer if the `CreateDefaultSubobject` function has a possibility of failing or returning a null pointer. If the function is known to always return a valid object, checking may not be necessary in that case.